# where to put jar files inside repository

Tags: java, jar, repository

I've got a Java project hosted on github. My project needs few custom `.jar` files to be imported. Since I was to be able to run the project anywhere, I want to include jar files inside the git repository. Is there a recommended, conventional place where jar files should be kept, e.g. `lib` dir of the root project directory?

PS

At the moment I'm not using Maven and I'm not considering it.

Comment: Why are you not considering maven?  You shouldn't commit compiled code or jars that are available elsewhere through maven dependencies.

Comment: @david99world: I know it's possible with maven and it's easy, but I'd like to learn how to do without it. Before maven got popular, people had to do it somehow - and I'd like to find out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual case is actually a *lib* folder. Or *webapp/WEB-INF/lib* it is a web application.

But ths usual case is bad. I would not put jars in my source management system. If you need to add references to another project, you might consider having a look a [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) (though you are using Github).